# DialogViewController frame resize after UIImagePickerController

Tags: xamarin.ios, uiimagepickercontroller, dialogviewcontroller

i have some problem with DialogViewController. This is modified example from xamarin monotouch examples(BubbleCell) that shows the issue [dowload](http://www.dropbox.com/sh/2ep8ua1bplorj57/4LWXDtaOy-/BubbleCell.zip).

Shortly, i have UIImagePickerController from [TweetStation](http://github.com/migueldeicaza/TweetStation), that collects image for profile photo. And DialogViewController below, that collects some information about user. As last row of DVC , i have custom UITableViewCell with textfield. If I just click on the field, it will work fine (I set ContentOffset to the general UIScrollView, and the textfiled moves just above the keyboard). But if I first click on the picture(that call UIImagePickerController), and collect image(or not , no matter), and after that click on textfiled, then the frame of DVC will displayed incorrectly(resize frame).

To see problem run project, press login-> chat with robot-> click textfiled on last row -> see correct animation-> click return on keyboard-> click on image -> select picture(or not , no matter) -> again click textfiled -> see wrong animation

TableView.ScrollEnabled=false on DVC is mandatory property.

How can i solve this problem ?

Thanks